# zipping a folder using 7zip and python sub process module

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, 7zip

I am trying to zip a folder using subprocess:

```
zip_file = "7z a \"%s\" \"%s\"" %( afterzip, beforezip )
retV = subprocess.Popen(zip_file, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
outData = retV.stdout.readlines()
```

this particular code works for files not folders.
The zip itself is created but it is empty. The command itself works for folders in CMD. All help is appreciated.

Comment: I figured it out. It was an issue with \ and /. Thanks